# Which site could I download ESRI shapefile for training on QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I would like to download ESRI shapefile from free source for training on QGIS. I need shapefile for polygon and line, so I can do some training to use QGIS 3. Please advice me also, how can I learn using QGIS 3?

Comment: A web search with "download shp" return many site... also the QGIS website has a training material section....

Comment: QGIS installers also bundle optional training datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of resources you can choose from to download shapefiles in both vector lines and polygons. Try the Government of Canada Open Data Portal at:

https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset?res_format=SHP

You could also practice by creating your own vector layer in QGIS by clicking *New Vector Layer*.